# How would you write an algorithm for traversing an array of arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, multidimensional-array

How might you write a recursive function in javascript for traversing a matrix/grid (array of arrays) type data structure? So lets say:

```
  var o = "water"; // water
  var M = "land"; // land

  var board = [ 
    [o,o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o],
    [o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o,o],
    [o,o,o,o,M,o,o,M,M,o],
    [o,o,M,o,M,o,o,o,M,o],
    [o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o],
    [o,o,o,M,M,M,M,o,o,o],
    [M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M],
    [o,o,M,M,o,M,M,M,o,o],
    [o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o],
    [M,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o]
  ];
```

I want to find out what the most amount of connected "land" is, starting on any element and recursively traversing the map from there. But only counting elements that are connected directly by at least 1 element in any direction (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W) .For instance, running the recursive function on this map should return 30.

Comment: You cannot ask this way (convert some program from Ruby to PHP). First you need to try yourself, and post your current code with a question to solve, second nobody will know what Chris Pine has written in his Chapter 10. Please read this: [ask] to rewrite your post. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to better phrase the question... Thanks!

Comment: @mins I humbly disagree with this moderation. Namely many beginners learn through Chris Pine's famous book, it is one of the most mature and best freely available introductions to programming and this chapter is the pinnacle of the book which teaches recursion. Many beginners find it difficult and google searches turn out very few good results because SO moderators take out the keyword from questions like these. Please undo your edit.

Comment: @mins On naming: "traversing an array of arrays" doesn't describe the problem it only describes the data structure. If you really need a generic description this is a Depth First Search recursive board traversal with flip and count.

Comment: @ilonabudapesti: I'm sorry if I made you upset by not knowing Chris Pine. The cause of the moderation was because there was no own solution to fix, only a request to do the work from scratch. This is part of the [site's rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "*Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it*". My personal opinion is that you don't help a learner by providing the answer; instead show where the way is and let them continue their walk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a great example for recursion. Here it is in JavaScript.

```
  function continentCounter (board, x, y) {
  // base cases:
  // we fell off the board 
  // or we fell into water
  // or we counted it already
    if (board[x] === undefined || board[x][y] !== 'land') {
      return 0;
    }

    var count = 1;
    board[x][y] = 'counted land';

    count += continentCounter(board, x-1, y-1);
    count += continentCounter(board, x-1, y);
    count += continentCounter(board, x-1, y+1);

    count += continentCounter(board, x, y-1);
    count += continentCounter(board, x, y+1);

    count += continentCounter(board, x+1, y-1);
    count += continentCounter(board, x+1, y);
    count += continentCounter(board, x+1, y+1);


    return count;
  }


  var o = "water"; // water
  var M = "land"; // land

  var board = [ 
    [o,o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o],
    [o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o,o],
    [o,o,o,o,M,o,o,M,M,o],
    [o,o,M,o,M,o,o,o,M,o],
    [o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o],
    [o,o,o,M,M,M,M,o,o,o],
    [M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,M],
    [o,o,M,M,o,M,M,M,o,o],
    [o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o],
    [M,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o]
  ];

  continentCounter(board, 0, 4); // 30
```